# SSR compatible Components Library for Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, frontend, vue-component, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I'm a Backend Engineer, I have been developing a side project for several months, and now it's time to create the Frontend. I'm not well versed on frontend stuff, is very stressful for me to do Frontend Dev, so I decided to pick up Nuxt and do this as fast as possible (I like the SSR too).

The problem I'm facing right now is that most of the component libraries I found for Vue/Nuxt are not compatible with SSR, so for them to work in my project, I must declare the plugins as 'client' and wrap the premade components they offer on the `<client-only>` tag.

I can't find a library that supports SSR with Nuxt, the closest is Vuetify, which claims to have support for SSR, but I'm looking for something more basic, lightweight.

Is out there something like this for Nuxt?

Thanks!

PD: Im using Nuxt + TailwindCSS

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to use nuxt-cli (`create-nuxt-app`), this way when going through installation process you'll be asured you always have plugins and addons that are compatible and automatically pre-configured with your nuxt installation, like for the moment when you go along with:

`npx create-nuxt-app <project-name>`

you will get under UI framework following options to choose from:

- Ant Design Vue
- Bootstrap Vue
- Buefy
- Bulma
- Chakra UI
- Element
- Framevuerk
- iView
- Tachyons
- Tailwind CSS
- Vuesax
- Vuetify.js

Whichever you prefer